# How can I make a game object shoot a projectile in Unity 3D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is my first question so I'm sorry if I didn't get the format *just* right.

I just installed unity yesterday and I'm working on a 2D Shoot 'Em Up project. The game plays in 2D but uses 3D objects, inspired by Ikaruga.

I currently have a capsule with a character controller that I can move around, but I am having issues getting it to shoot projectiles.

I want to make a 3D projectile that will shoot forwards always, no following the mouse or anything.

My camera setup is all sorted for a top-down perspective, it's just the shooting where I've found a roadblock.

I've tried looking for a tutorial, but it is really difficult to find any example as I feel like this is a pretty obscure question. Any help is hugely appreciated if anyone knows how to make this work!

Answer (score -1):

It would be a lot more helpful if you included some code/details of what you have already tried, and why that doesn't work.

As it stands, from reading your question it sounds like (though may not be the case that) you haven't made any efforts to solve this on your own - this is likely why no-one has yet to offer an answer of commented.

Moving on from there, firing a weapon in game is quite simple once you understand movement and object instantiating (or instancing).

My advice is to watch tutorials, and continue learning. At first you will be mostly pausing the tutorials to copy the code, and referring back to that copied code for later similar projects. But after a while you will begin to gain a better understanding and start writing your own functions.

Anyway, here is a great tutorial that shows you three different methods you can use to fire guns in [Unity Three Ways to Shoot Projectiles in Unity](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nke5JKPiQTw).

Comment: I actually found a tutorial which was exactly what I was looking for and linked it in a reply. For some reason, however, that comment was deleted by a moderator. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯